# How to query Last inserted row for each group in oracle 10

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g

I have two tables about users where I want to join two tables and show the latest remarks of each user

bellow is table

[image]

I want to query the latest remarks for each user (1 remark per user)

bellow query I have written but it returns multiple remarks per user if date and time is the same for remarks

```
SELECT a.cust_id,b.remarks,b.contact_date,b.contact_time FROM customers a,(select * from customer_review
where (cust_id,contact_time,contact_date) in (select cust_id, max(contact_time),max(contact_date) from customer_review group by cust_id)
) b WHERE  a.cust_id=b.cust_id;
```

[image]

Please give any solution to query 1 remark per user
(Note: sorry I cannot alter column details if any)
Live link [Oracle Live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/i62hony8hpgu5j76mweyp8vte)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query:

```
   Select * from 
    (SELECT a.cust_id,b.remarks,b.contact_date,b.contact_time FROM customers a,(select * from customer_review
        where (cust_id,contact_time,contact_date) in 
    (select cust_id, max(contact_time),max(contact_date) from customer_review group by cust_id order by max(contact_time) desc,max(contact_date) desc)
        ) b WHERE  a.cust_id=b.cust_id) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select cr.*
from (select cr.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by contact_date desc, contact_time desc) as seqnum
      from customer_review cr
     ) cr
where seqnum = 1;
```

For your sample results, you do not need the `customer` table, unless you want customers with no reviews.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed problem this way;

```
select a.policyid
        ,a.startdate
        ,a.enddate
        ,a.createdate
        ,b.reasondescpsr reasondesc
    from policysuspend       a
        ,policysuspendreason b
   where a.reasonid = b.reasonid
     and (a.policyid, a.createdate) in (select policyid
                                              ,max(createdate)
                                          from policysuspend
                                         group by policyid)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can join and use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select 
    c.cust_id,
    c.cust_name,
    r.remarks,
    r.contact_time
from customers c
inner join customer_review r 
    on  r.cust_id = c.cust_id
    and r.contact_time = (
        select max(contact_time)
        from customer_review r1
        where r1.cust_id = r.cust_id
    )
```

With an index on `customer_review(cust_id, contact_time)`, this should be a very efficient option.

If you don't need information coming from the `customers` table (like customer name for example), then no need to `join`:

```
select r.*
from customer_review r 
where contact_time = (
    select max(contact_time)
    from customer_review r1
    where r1.cust_id = r.cust_id
)
```